# Existence of limit of $x_n=d(a,b_n)$ doesn't imply $b_n$ having a limit

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, metric-spaces

I made this question to myself. I'm not sure if what I'm thinking it is right or not.

> **Question.** Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Find an example that existence of limit of $x_n=d(a,b_n)$ doesn't imply $b_n$ having a limit.

My example:
Let $X=\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus (0,0)$ equipped with Euclidean metric. Consider $a=(0,1) \in X$, and let $b_n=(\frac{1}{n},0) \subset X$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Now, $x_n=d((0,1),(\frac{1}{n},0))$ is a sequence of real values. Then limit of $x_n$ is $1$, but $b_n$ has no limit because $(0,0)$ is not in $X$.

Comment: look good to me.  you may try to think about an example when $X$ is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a correct example!

It's not the only way that the statement can fail though; consider $a = (0, 0)$ and $b_n = (\sin n, \cos n)$ on $\mathbf{R}^2$ with the Euclidean metric so that $d(a, b_n) = 1$ for all  $n$.